# Angular2 Modulo Http subir archivo soporte FormData

Tags: angularjs-2.0, http, archivo, formdata

Estoy necesitando subir un archivo en angular 2 pero sin tener que convertirlo a base64 y mandarlo como string, alguno sabe si la librería angular/http soporta [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) para poder subir un archivo, si no es así, que otra alternativa tengo.

Saludos

Comment: es soportado (file: FormData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre dar con la solución de como enviar un FormData enviándolo dentro del body, cabe aclarar que las primeras versiones de angular2 no soportaban form data, de ahi mi pregunta, y se tenia que recurrir a soluciones alternativas como usar peticiones XHTTP crudas

template.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="onArchivoSeleccionado($event)">
```

component.ts

```
public onArchivoSeleccionado($event) {
    if ($event.target.files.length === 1) {
        this.subirArchivo($event.target.files[0]).subscribe(response => {
            // respuesta
        },
        error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}


public subirArchivo(file): Observable<string> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('fileName', file.name);
    const url = "http://"; //destino en el servidor
    const headers = new Headers({});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(url, formData, options).map(response => response.text());
}
```